# Regex to extract multiple sentences while discarding a specific one

Tags: c#, regex

In: `preferences = 'Hello my name is paul. I hate puzzles.'`
I want to extract `Hello my name is paul.`

In: `preferences = 'Salutations my name is richard. I love pizza. I hate rain.'`
I want to extract `Salutations my name is richard. I love pizza.`

In: `preferences = 'Hi my name is bob. I enjoy ice cream.'`
I want to extract `Hi my name is bob. I enjoy ice cream.`

In other words, I would like to

- **always** discard `preferences = '`
- discard **any last** sentence (delimited by `.`) that has the word `hate` in, **if present**.
- discard the final `'`

My problem is that my regex stops at the first `.` and doesn't extract the subsequent sentences.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of `preferences = 'I love you. I hate you. I killed  you.'` ?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im It would be `I love you. I hate you. I killed you.` because hate does not appear in the last sentence.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino It's in C# but, I'm curious, why would it matter?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My current, non-functioning Regex: `(?:preferences[\s=]*')(.*?)(?:\..*hate.*)?(?:')`

Comment: I don't know the C# regex implementation, but in `sed` the following approach works: 1) replace `preferences = '(.*+)'` with the captured group; 2) replace `\.[^.]*hate[^.]*\.?$` with an empty string. `$` means the end of the string.

Comment: The reason the programming language matters is that regex is not the same everywhere. Mostly the same, but not exactly. Perl is slightly different from PCRE, which is different from Javascript RegExp, which is slightly different from .NET System.Text.RegularExpressions, and so on.  For example Javascript RegExp lacks negative lookbehind; PCRE and C# have this.

Comment: This problem statement has many cases, and although it sounds simple, as you moved beyond parsing a string into language processing, it is anything but trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using a regular expression:

```
^preferences\s*=\s*'(.*?\.)(?:[^.]*\bhate\b[^.]*\.)?'$
```

That one isn't too tricky:

- `(.*?\.)` - Match your expected output, that will be captured in group `$1`. The pattern matches "sentences" (as you've defined), but lazily (`*?`), as few as it must.
- `(?:[^.]*\bhate\b[^.]*\.)?` - optionally match the last sentence, but only if it contains "hate". If it can match, and it is the last sentence, the matching engine will not backtrack, and the last sentence will not be included in the captured group.

Here's a working example in Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/qTuMmB3ySj
(I've added `\r\n` in a few places, to avoid `[^.]` matching new lines)

Honestly though, you can do better than a single regular expression here, if you can avoid it.

Comment: Does this require a period somewhere to match?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Kobi. I added to it to cater for more punctuation marks: `preferences\s*=\s*'(.*?(?:\!|\.))(?:[^!?.]*\bhate\b[.\s!]*)?'`

Comment: @BlazingFrog - You have to be consistent with delimeters. What you have won't work. Since your allowing apostrophe as both delimeter and content, the ^$ anchors are needed as the only real delimeter. In that case, its better to focus on what you don't want. Use this `^\s*preferences\s*=\s*'((?:(?![^!?.]*\bhate\b[^!?.]*[.\s!?]*'\s*$).)*).*'\s*$`

Answer (score 1):

While This is not using RegEx, it will achieve what you are aiming for

```
List<string> resultsList = new List<string);


for(int i = 0; i < preferences.Count; i++)
{
    List<string> tempList = new List<string);
    //creating the substring eliminates the "preferences = '" as well as the "'" at end of string
    //this line also splits each string from the preferences string list into the tempList array
    tempList = preferences[i].Substring(15, preferences[i].Length - 15 - 1).Split('.').ToList();

    string buildFinalString = "";

    //traverse tempList and only add string to buildFinalString if it does not contain "hate"
    foreach(string x in tempList)
    {
        if(!x.Contains("hate").ToUpper() || !x.Contains("hate").ToLower())
        {
             buildFinalString = buildFinalString + " " + x;
        }
    }
    resultsList.Add(buildFinalString);
}
```

or if you only wanted to check the last string in the "tempList" array for the word hate, this would also be possible...

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately, I need to get it all in regex since I don't have access to the code but only the regex that is stored in a table.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with 2 regex. The first is used to strip the `preferences = '...'`, and the second is to eliminate any sentence with the word "hate".    The 2nd regex uses a positive lookbehind to replace setntences with the keyword with the empty string.

```
String[] tests = {
    "preferences = 'Hello my name is Paul. I hate puzzles.'",
    "preferences = 'Salutations my name is Richard. I love pizza. I hate rain.'",
    "preferences = 'Hi my name is Bob. Regex turns me on.'"};
var re1 = new Regex("preferences = '(.*)'");
var re2 = new Regex("([^\\.]+(?<=.*\\bhate\\b.*)).\\s*");

for (int i=0; i < tests.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, tests[i]);
    var m = re1.Match(tests[i]);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        var s = m.Groups[1].ToString();
        s = re2.Replace(s,"");
        Console.WriteLine("   {1}", i, s);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This may not be exactly what you want, since you asked to eliminate only *the last* sentence if it contains the flag word. But it's easy to adjust if you truly want to strip only the last sentence if it contains the word. In that case you just need to append a $ to the end of re2.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately, I need to get it all in regex since I don't have access to the code but only the regex that is stored in a table.

Answer (score 0):

One of these might work -

Results in Match[1] buffer

```
preferences\s*=\s*'([^']*?)(?:(?<=[.'])[^.']*hate[^.']*\.\s*)?'
```

or

Results in Match[1] buffer

```
preferences\s*=\s*'([^']*?)(?=(?<=[.'])[^.']*hate[^.']*\.\s*'|')
```

or

(.Net only)
Results in Match[0] buffer

```
(?<=preferences\s*=\s*')[^']*?(?=(?<=[.'])[^.']*hate[^.']*\.\s*'|')
```

edit: Not using \b around 'hate', nor begin/end constructs ^$, feel free to add them if thats what you need. As a side not, its puzzling how apostrophe and period are used in the context of delimiting a string variable that has free form text in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw your reply after I successfully implemented Kobi's solution so I haven't tested it.

Comment: Don't worry, there is no solution on this page.